# Pandas: select rows with column datatype

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame where a timestamp column contains mixed types. Some rows have the time reported in Unix timestamps (numeric), some rows have the time reported as iso-format strings, and the remaining rows have Pandas datetime objects.

Is there a way for me to select all of the rows that have a non-datetime object in the timestamp column? I would like to run pd.to_datetime to convert the timestamp column of these rows to datetime objects.

The built-in [select_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) does not do what I want. This library function selects the columns that (do not) have a certain type, but I want to select the rows where a given column value is (not) a specific type.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [
        Timestamp('2019-03-31 00:00:00-0400', tz='US/Eastern'),
        '2019-01-31 12:00:00-0700',
        1551000000
    ] })
```

Goal:

```
def get_not_datetime_rows(df):
    """Output the last two rows."""
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example?

Comment: Added an example above.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this (assuming `df` is your DataFrame and "Timestamp" is the column in question)?

```
from datetime import datetime
idx = df["Timestamp"].apply(lambda x: type(x) != datetime)
```

Then use `idx` to slice your DataFrame

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using apply? My dataframe is millions of rows and apply is usually much slower than indexing or slicing based approaches.

Comment: @charmander123: You could use a list comprehension like so:
`idx = [type(x) == datetime for x in df['Timestamp'].values]`

My rough testing on a DataFrame of one million rows indicates it's ~30% faster than `apply`.